# R: create data.table with periodic function

Tags: r, function, dataframe, data.table, tidyr

I would like to create a data.table in [tidy](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) form containing the columns articleID, period and demand (with articleID and period as key). The demand is subject to a random function with input data from another data.frame (params). It is created at runtime for differing numbers of periods.

It is easy to do this in "non-tidy" form:

```
#example data
params <- data.frame(shape=runif(10),   rate=runif(10)*2)
rownames(params) <- letters[1:10]
periods <- 10

# create non-tidy data with one column for each period
df <- replicate(nrow(params), 
                   rgamma(periods,shape=params[,"shape"], rate=params[,"rate"]))
rownames(df) <- rownames(params)
```

Is there a "tidy" way to do this creation? I would need to replicate the rgamma(), but I am not sure how to make it use the parameters of the corresponding article. I tried starting with a Cross Join from data.table:

```
dt <- CJ(articleID=rownames(params), per=1:periods, demand=0)
```

but I don't know how to pass the rgamma to the dt[,demand] directly and correctly at creation nor how to change the values now without using some ugly for loop. I also considered using gather() from the tidyr package, but as far as I can see, I would need to use a for loop either.

It does not really matter to me whether I use data.frame or data.table for my current use case. Solutions for any (or both!) would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Would something like `e <- quote(rgamma(periods,shape=params[,"shape"], rate=params[,"rate"])); do.call(CJ, list(articleID = rownames(params), per = 1:periods, demand = e))` do it?  I'm not quite sure what the result should look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll do (note that it assumes that `params` is sorted by row names, if not you can convert it to a `data.table` and merge the two):

```
CJ(articleID=rownames(params), per=1:periods)[,
  demand := rgamma(.N, shape=params[,"shape"], rate=params[,"rate"]), by = per]
```